# cross browseing ie

Tags: html, cross-browser

I have [this email creative](http://lirantadmor.co.il/email). The bottom box is placed ok on ff and chrome, but in IE it's getting a bit weird.

What do I need to add/remove from my code in order for the bottom box to appear correctly?

Thanks.

here is the code:

```
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
p
        {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: right;
        }

        a:link
        {
            color: #990000;
            text-decoration: none;

        }
        a:visited
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #990000;
        }
        a:hover
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #990000;
        }
        img
        {
            border: none;
        }
        body{

            margin:0px;
        }
        </style>
<div style="text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;background-color: #EEF3FA">
    <div style="text-align: right; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;background-color: #FFF;width: 720px;margin: 0px auto;">
    <br />
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl" width="700">
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <td colspan="3">
                    <a href="http://www.shvoong.co.il/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/head.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" /></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="border:2px #060">
                    <a href="http://www.shvoong.co.il/minisites/kfarsaba/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/tophaedr1.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-right:23px;" /></a></td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl" width="700" style="margin-right:17px;">

                <!-- right -->
                <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="156" height="500">

    <table width="156" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
    style="background-color: B4D336">
    <tr>
    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner2.gif" width="14" 
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    <td width="172"></td>

    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner1.gif" width="14"
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    </tr>

<tr>





</tr>
<tr>

<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner4.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

<td></td>

<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner3.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

</tr>

</table>

            <table width="156" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
    style="background-color: 3778BC;margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>
    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner2_b.gif" width="14" 
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    <td width="172"></td>

    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner1_b.gif" width="14"
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    </tr>
<tr>







</tr>
<tr>

<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner4_b.gif" width="14" 
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    <td width="172"></td>

    <td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner3_b.gif" width="14"
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

</tr>
</table>





                </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="156" >


                <table width="156" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
    style="background-color: 3778BC">
    <tr>
    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner2_b.gif" width="14" 
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    <td width="172"></td>

    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner1_b.gif" width="14"
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    </tr>
<tr>







</tr>
<tr>

<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner4_b.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

<td></td>

<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner3_b.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

</tr>
</table>

                <table width="156" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
    style="background-color: B4D336;margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>

    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner2.gif" width="14" 
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    <td width="172"></td>

    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner1.gif" width="14"
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    </tr>
<tr>






</tr>
<tr>


<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner4.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

<td></td>

<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner3.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

</tr>
</table>



                </td>
                                <td valign="top" width="156">

    <table width="156" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
    style="background-color: B4D336">
    <tr>

    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner2.gif" width="14" 
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    <td width="172"></td>

    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner1.gif" width="14"
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    </tr>
<tr>





</tr>
<tr>


<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner4.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

<td></td>

<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner3.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

</tr>
</table>

                <table width="156" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
    style="background-color: 3778BC;margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>
    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner2_b.gif" width="14" 
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    <td width="172"></td>


    <td width="14" valign="top"><img src="Images/rounded_corner1_b.gif" width="14"
    height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>

    </tr>
<tr>





</tr>
<tr>

<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner4_b.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

<td></td>


<td width="14" valign="bottom"><img src="Images/rounded_corner3_b.gif" width="14" height="14"
border="0" alt="..." /></td>

</tr>
</table>




                </td>
                <!-- space -->

                <!-- left -->
                <td  valign="top" width="180">
                <table width="180" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
style="background-color: B4D336">

<tr>

<td></td>

<td align="center"><a href="http://www.shvoong.co.il/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/left.jpg" width="180" 
height="188" border="0" alt="..." /></a></td>

<td></td>

</tr>

</table>
                        <table width="180" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
style="background-color: B4D336">

<tr>


<td></td>

<td align="center"><a href="http://www.shvoong.co.il/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/left.jpg" width="180" 
height="188" border="0" alt="..." /></a></td>

<td></td>

</tr>

</table>
                        <table width="180" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
style="background-color: B4D336">

<tr>

<td></td>


<td align="center"><a href="http://www.shvoong.co.il/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/left.jpg" width="180" 
height="188" border="0" alt="..." /></a></td>

<td></td>

</tr>

</table>
                    <table width="180" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
style="background-color: B4D336">

<tr>

<td></td>

<td align="center"><a href="http://www.shvoong.co.il/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/left.jpg" width="180" 
height="188" border="0" alt="..." /></a></td>


<td></td>

</tr>

</table>
            </table>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl" width="700">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <a href="http://www.shvoong.co.il/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/pre.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 8px; margin-top: -20px;" /></a></td>

                    <td colspan="3">
                    <a href="http://www.shvoong.co.il/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/logoleft.gif" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 11px; margin-top: -10px;" /></a></td>
            </tr>


            </table>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this is HTML one should receive in an email?

Comment: ... in which case, testing in IE is not the *most* useful thing you could be doing

Answer (score -1):

First of all I would highly recommend to **stop using `<table>` tags for structuring a page**. Thats what `<div>`'s are for.

IE is known to be problematic, usually I would add custom CSS rules that only apply to IE, by using the asterisk (*) marker.

```css
#myDiv{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    *top: 15px; /* Should be read only be IE */
    *left: 8px; /* Should be read only be IE */
}
```

Shai

Comment: It's an email creative. As much as we hate it, tables are still pretty much required for email-client compatibility.

Comment: Didn't notice it :) Even tho the OP doesn't even have `html` tags, which should be there even for emails.

Comment: the problem is on a tbody,so can I give a specific css for a tbody? also,since it's an email creative,will the css work on client emails programs?

Comment: How would you know without trying? :)

Comment: The email standards project (http://www.email-standards.org/) is an excellent resource for what is supported

Comment: @Shai: the asterisk hack is very dangerous (http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml); I wouldn't use it personally. Even if we WERE talking browsers, rather than email clients :-)

Comment: @Shai: also, your comment syntax is invalid CSS - fixing with an edit

Comment: @BobbyJack I wouldn't call it very dangerous - Its just a dirty trick, Sometimes getting cross-browser compatibility, especially on IE - requires those dirty tricks. About my comment syntax, I didn't plan for it to be valid CSS - i was just writing it as a remark.

Comment: @Shai: OK, "very dangerous" might be an exageration (particularly if compared to, say, swimming with sharks) but there are safer alternatives. Also, as soon as you put 'code' up on the web, and especially when you mark it as 'code', like it or not, sooner or later someone will copy+paste it and use it in a production environment.

Comment: @BobbyJack SO isn't for complete noobs. If you copy paste and you can't realize the comments are messing with your css - something is seriously wrong :)

Comment: @BobbyJack I understand where you're coming from, but seriously - editing such a minor thing is a bit petty in my opinion :)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to stop using tables for the layout.